# can we run javascript in .net window application

Tags: c#, .net, jquery

hi I am  developing a  application  in which i want to show pop up and loading image . for this i need to use jquery   can it possible to run  these script in .net window application form as iam not using  asp .net .

Comment: technically, you can run Javascript in the application using JScript.NET, but jquery wouldn't have any chance of working as you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

You can add in an internet browser control onto your windows form and load/run the javascript within the browser control.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You must open a popups in windows applications byc creating new form instances.

```
new PopupForm().Show();
```